# Files Written to External USB Disk are taking up Internal Storage Space

Tags: debian, raspbian, fstab, external-hdd

Forgive me if I'm in the wrong Stack, this seemed like a more general Linux thing, so I posted here. Np if I need to take it elsewhere. Also I'm pretty new to Linux so please be patient.

Hardware= Raspberry Pi 3
OS= Raspbian Buster, apt-get update and upgrade applied
Application= PLEX server, NAS and networked TimeMachine target

I have a 3 TB USB disk that I formatted gpt/EXT4 the issue that I'm having is that any file copied to it is instead taking up space on the internal SD card.

I have created the directory /mnt/nas and set that as the mount point for the drive at boot using fstab:

UUID=F00F00F00 /mnt/nas ext4 defaults,auto,users,rx,nofail 0 0,x-systemd.device-timeout=15

I get no errors- however, when I go to copy files I get some "no storage left" error because the files are trying to fill my SD card.

I have attached a screenshot showing that after transferring a large folder /mnt/nas has the same Free Space/Total Space as Filesystem. What am I doing wrong that files aren't making it onto the external disk?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: The mount likely didn't happen. What says `df /mnt/nas`? Does it show the root FS or the NAS one? Is the UUID in `fstab` the right one? Iff the NAS has a different UUID that entry will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @xenoid suggested, it seems you've not actually *mounted* the USB drive that you've connected to your RPi. Perhaps the easiest way to confirm that is to check as follows:

```bsh
$ lsblk --fs
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL       UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda
└─sda1      exfat  SANDISK16GB 5B00-9E5C                            /home/pi/mntThumbDrv
sdb
└─sdb1      ext4   PASSPORT2TB 86645948-d127-4991-888c-a466b7722f05 /home/pi/mntPassport
sdc
└─sdc1      ext4   SANDISK8GB  e5cb39a9-b041-4339-92f5-4172201a4b1a /home/pi/mntBackupDrv
mmcblk0
├─mmcblk0p1 vfat   boot        5DB0-971B                            /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 ext4   rootfs      060b57a8-62bd-4d48-a471-0d28466d1fbb /
```

You can plug your USB disk into your RPi, and then run the command as shown above. You will get a similar output.

Let's decipher this:

The `lsblk` command lists block devices. I prefer it because it's simple to use, and easy to read. `man lsblk` will give you all the details.

As you can see, there are 5 columns in the output. Let's look in the `NAME` column at the one for `sdb` as this is likely to be similar to your drive. First know that the name `sdb` designates a `device` name that was assigned by the system, and is indicative of the media type. Immediately below `sdb` is the name of a `partition`; `sdb1` in this case. So - `partitions` belong to `devices`. A `device` must have at least one `partition` to be usable, and it may have more than one. Subsequent `partitions` in this case would be called `sdb2`, `sdb3`, etc.

Your USB drive (the `device`) should have a `NAME` like `sdb`, `sdc`, etc. Since you've said you created a partition, and formatted it with the `ext4` filesystem, you should also see a numbered `partition` listed immediately below the `device`. In the row for that `partition`, the `FSTYPE` column should show `ext4`.

The `LABEL` column may contain a string of characters that were assigned - perhaps by you when you `formatted` the drive. I'll assume you know how to change this label if you like. The `UUID` column will contain a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) that may be used in your `fstab` entry.

And finally, the "payoff": the `MOUNTPOINT` column will tell you if your drive is mounted, and where the mount point is located in your RPi's filesystem. Based on your question, I believe the `MOUNTPOINT` column for your USB drive partition will be empty/vacant - indicating that it is not actually mounted. If this is the case, you are writing your files to `/mnt/nas/` which is just another directory in your RPi's file system - until your USB is actually `mount`ed there!

So, to answer your question:

> What am I doing wrong that files aren't making it onto the external disk?

You have failed to `mount` the USB drive.

You may want to first try using the `mount` command to mount your drive manually; for example:

```bsh
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/nas
```

Once you've done that, try writing files as before & note the difference. Then, construct an entry in your `/etc/fstab` following the instructions in `man fstab`. You may also find [this "how-to" on GitHub](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/ExternalDrives.md) helpful.

Otherwise, or if you're still having problems, edit your question to include the output of your `lsblk --fs` command, and we'll go from there.

Comment: I was able to mount using the mount command which tells me that something was off with my fstab entry. I then made incremental changes to suspect options using umount and mount -a (which calls on the the table iirc) to check if my changes worked.

In the end, I had to delete the timeout option and set permissions to rw (were rx).

New entry: UUID= F00F00F00 /mnt/nas ext4 defaults,auto,users,rw,nofail 0 0

Thank you very much. I wish there were more people like you on the internet. Very clear and detailed answer delivered in a kind way.

Comment: When I'm on the RPi, everything works as expected. The issue that I now have is that If I'm connected to the RPi via SSH, VNC, or the directory (/mnt/nas) over AFP (can connect just fine and read just fine) I cannot write to the disk. I'm assuming this means I haven't mounted the disk with correct permissions. Should I start a new question? What’s the proper stack etiquette?

Comment: @Matsumura_Fishworks: First, thanks for the kind words. Second, it would probably be best for you to start a new question. However, the issue is almost certainly permissions as you have guessed. Here's the thing: Once you begin sharing via Samba, a 2nd set of permissions and authentication comes into play. In addition to your Linux permissions and authentication, you now have Samba permissions and authentication. Look at this [GitHub page](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/FileShare.md); hopefully all will become clear once you read through that.